# Why I got unsatisfactory result when I use svm model in scikit-learner to recognize handwriting figures in MNIST?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, mnist

I use the `svm` model in `scikit-learner` to predict handwriting in MNIST.

However, the result I got is confused. When I use  trained model to predict training set that already used in learning procedure the accuracy is 100%

When dealing with the test data I only got about 11% accuracy.

I cannot find out the reason except overfitting. Does overfitting has such a strong influence on the outcome?

```
# coding:utf-8
from numpy import *
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.externals import joblib
def loadData(fileName):
    fr = open(fileName)
    numFeat = len(fr.readline().split(',')) - 1       
    featMatTrain = []                                        
    labelVecTrain = []                                      
    featMatTest = []                                       
    labelVecTest = []                                     
    i = 0
    for line in fr.readlines():
        i = i + 1
        if i != 1 and i <=30000:
             curLine = line.strip().split(',')        
             curLine = map(float,curLine)              
             labelVecTrain.append(curLine[0])           
             featMatTrain.append(curLine[1:numFeat])       
        if i >= 30000:
             curLine = line.strip().split(',')      
             curLine = map(float,curLine)              
             labelVecTest.append(curLine[0])              
             featMatTest.append(curLine[1:numFeat])      
    print '*************************** the training data we got: *****************************'
    print 'featMat:''type of element:',type(featMatTrain) ,'shape of featMat:', shape(featMatTrain)
    print 'labelVec:''type of element:',type(labelVecTrain),'shape of labelVec:',shape(labelVecTrain)
    print 'featMat:''type of element:',type(featMatTest) ,'shape of featMat:', shape(featMatTest)
    print 'labelVec:''type of element:',type(labelVecTest),'shape of labelVec:',shape(labelVecTest)
    return array(featMatTrain),array(labelVecTrain),array(featMatTest),array(labelVecTest)

featMatTrain,labelVecTrain,featMatTest,labelVecTest= loadData('C:/Users/sun/Desktop/train.csv')    
clf = svm.SVC()                                                  
clf.fit(featMatTrain,labelVecTrain)                                           
joblib.dump(clf,'svmModel.pkl')                                     
print '***************** we finish training **********************'
labelVecPredict1 = clf.predict(featMatTrain)
labelVecPredict2 = clf.predict(featMatTest)
print '***************** we finish predicting **********************'
count1 = 0.0
for i in range(len(featMatTrain)):
    if labelVecPredict1[i] == labelVecTrain[i]:
        count1 = count1 + 1
print '************* the result of predicting training set ***************'
print 'the number of figures that predict right: ',count1
print 'the accuary is :',count1/len(featMatTrain)
count2 = 0.0
for i in range(len(featMatTest)):
    if labelVecPredict2[i] == labelVecTest[i]:
        count2 = count2 + 1
print '************ the result to predicting testing set ************'
print 'the number of figures that predict right:',count2
print 'the  accuary is:',count2/len(featMatTest)
```

Comment: There's not much anyone can do unless you include actual code/data.

Comment: I really want to,unfortunately I have only 2 reputation

Comment: Just double check: Have you applied the same preprocessor/transformer to test dataset as well? Are y-classes well balanced?

Comment: improve grammar, spelling and formatting

Comment: @sunzhaoxing, reputation has nothing to do with including code. Edit your question, and cut-and-paste your code in using the formatting tags.

Comment: @scytale,thanks, actually this is what I want to improve now

Answer (score 0):

There are some reason will cause model overfitting.

1. You use too powerful model on small dataset. Maybe you can try some linear model.
2. Your training data set is too small to be trained, so you can add some training data from testing data set.

How do you divide the MINST dataset? You may have the imbalance cut on data set.

Comment: 30000 trainning examples,12000 testing examples

Comment: How about your testing data and training data ratio in each label.

Comment: ******** the number of each figure in training set *************
the number of 0 is 2937           1 is 3331        2 is 3020         3 is 3093
4 is 2932        5 is 2719               6 is 2970           7 is 3133     8 is 2889
9 is 2975                                                                                                 ******** the numbers of each figure in testing set *************
the numbers of 0 is 1196      1 is 1352         2 is 1157
3 is 1258        4 is 1140               5 is 1076            6 is 1167
 7 is 1268              8 is 1174               9 is 1213

Answer (score 0):

Overfitting absolutely has that much influence on the outcome. SVC is "strong learner", meaning that with enough features it can overfit any data set (other strong learners include DecisionTree's and NearestNeighbor models).

To defeat this, use a simpler model or use model averaging. Simpler models include LinearSVC; model averaging includes BaggingClassifier and RandomForestClassifier.

Comment: thank for your answer, I used  LinearSVC model and got a satisfied outcome. there also comes a question,what  the differences between SVC and LinearSVC ? When applied both to learn MNIST,LinearSVC took much shorter time than SVC did, just because LinearSVC implements "one-vs-the-rest"multi-class strategy?

Comment: No, it's because LinearSVC is a linear model: it fits a hyperplane directly to the feature space. SVC is a kernel/nonlinear model: it fits a hyperplane to a high dimensional nonlinear transform space. Read the [narrative documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/svm.html#classification)  thoroughly